# Trying to install firebase tools in reactjs app. but it's not working

Tags: npm, firebase-tools

I trying to install firebase tools in my Reactjs app. But it's not working:

```
command:"npm install -g firebase-tools"
error:"npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Administrator
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Administrator'     
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Administrator'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\rtyuiop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-21T08_52_21_511Z-debug-0.log"
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem